# Comparing number and timestamp in mysql produce unexpected results

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 20170930 < TIMESTAMP(20170831);
# 1
SELECT 20170930 > TIMESTAMP(20170831);
# 0
SELECT '20170930' < TIMESTAMP(20170831);
# 0
SELECT '20170930' > TIMESTAMP(20170831);
# 1
```

Docs：

> If one of the arguments is a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME column and the
>   other argument is a constant, the constant is converted to a timestamp
>   before the comparison is performed. This is done to be more
>   ODBC-friendly. This is not done for the arguments to IN(). To be safe,
>   always use complete datetime, date, or time strings when doing
>   comparisons. For example, to achieve best results when using BETWEEN
>   with date or time values, use CAST() to explicitly convert the values
>   to the desired data type.

It looks like MySQL does not convert Number into Timestamp before the comparison. Did I misunderstand it?

Comment: I'd rather say it is expected results) You've compared integer vs interger and string vs integer.

Comment: The first query correctly returns `0` on my server (5.5.44-MariaDB). But it returns `1` on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/151b2/1) using MySQL 5.6 :-(